# How to properly import and use the MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library for js) into a typescript react single page application?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, azure-ad-msal

### Problem

I can't seem to get the MSAL library to import properly into my typescript code. I'm using the [MSAL for JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) library (which is supposed to have typings) in a simple typescript/react project scaffolded using the create-react-app with react-typescript scripts. I'm new to typescript and not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if there is a problem with the MSAL package when using it with typescript projects.

### Details:

1. I added the MSAL package from NPM using `npm install --save msal`.
2. I attempted to import the MSAL into my .ts using different forms of `import {Msal} from 'msal';`
3. This results in a typescript error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'msal'. '<path>/node_modules/msal/out/msal.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
4. Thinking that was odd, I looked at the the node_module/msal/out folder and saw a 'msal.d.ts' file, which is what I would expect.
5. When I look at the contents of the [msal.d.ts](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/out/msal.d.ts) file, I don't see any exports, which I would normally expect to see.
6. I tried install the declaration from @types using `npm install --save-dev @types/msal`, but it doesn't exist.
7. I also tried importing it into my file using `let Msal = require('Msal');`, but get an error that the Msal.UserAgentApplication isn't a constructor.
8. I didn't have much luck trying to use the /// reference directive and adding a script tag to the main index.html. This also doesn't feel like the right way to solve the problem.

### ExampleMsal.ts

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';
import * as Msal from 'msal'; // <-- This line gives the error

class ExampleMsal{
    @observable 
    private _isLoggedIn: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this._isLoggedIn = false;
    }

    @computed 
    get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return this._isLoggedIn;
    }

    @action 
    signIn() {

        let userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication('<client-id>', null, 
        function (errorDes: string, token: string, error: string, tokenType: string) {
            // this callback is called after loginRedirect OR acquireTokenRedirect 
            // (not used for loginPopup/aquireTokenPopup)
        }
        );

        userAgentApplication.loginPopup(['user.read']).then(function(token: string) {
            let user = userAgentApplication.getUser();
            if (user) {
                // signin successful
                alert('success');
            } else {
                // signin failure
                alert('fail');
            }
        }, function (error: string) {
            // handle error
            alert('Error' + error);
        });        
        this._isLoggedIn = true;
    }

    @action 
    signOut() {
        this._isLoggedIn = false;
    }
}

export default ExampleMsal;
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "types": [
    "typePatches"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you have correctly mentioned - in the msal.d.ts there are no exports - its not a module, and therefore you should not try importing.

Instead you can use it like this:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/msal/out/msal.d.ts" />

const userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication("your_client_id", null, (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) =>
    {

    });
```

Note that even in readme they specify only one way of using their library - by including script tag, not by importing module. And further looking into their source code shows they are not using modules as well.

Comment: The reference path definition combined with including the js file from the CDN in my index.html got it working for me. I'll update back if I figure out a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Hi Nigel, can you upload your project to your Github? I am trying to find samples with React and MSAL. Thanks in advance

Comment: Later versions of MSAL seem to work well now, I'm using version 0.1.3, and it a simple: `import * as Msal from 'msal';` works well.

Answer (score 16):

It looks like the latest version of MSAL.js *does* have a CommonJS export. You can now just do the following in TypeScript (tested with version 2.3.3 of TypeScript and 0.1.3 of MSAL.js):

```
import * as Msal from 'msal';
```

Now in your `.ts` (or in my case `.tsx` file) you can, for instance, setup a click event handler and create a UserAgentApplication object:

```
// In you class somewhere
private userAgentApplication: any = undefined;

// The login button click handler
handleLoginClick = (event: any): void => {
    if (!this.userAgentApplication) {
        this.userAgentApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
            'clientID string', 'authority string or empty', this.authCallback, { cacheLocation: 'localStorage'});
    }
    // Other login stuff...
}

// In React render()
public render() {
    return (
        <Button
            bsStyle="warning"
            type="button"
            onClick={(e) => this.handleLoginClick(e)}
        >
        Log in
        </Button>
    );
}
```

Comment: I've been able to do what you suggested to new up a `UserAgentAppliation`, however, in previous code (where I loaded Msal from CDN), I did the following `Msal.Storage("localStorage").getItem(...)`.  This now gives an error when I use `import * as Msal from 'msal'`.  Is there a way to make that work?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and couldn't wait for the author to fix it, so forked and modified the original code. Just as a temporary fix you can use my version `msalx` instead of `msal`.

`npm install msalx`

You can find the source code and an example usage in react at: https://github.com/malekpour/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js#example

Comment: You sir are a hero

Answer (score 6):

If you install the exports-loader (`npm install exports-loader --save-dev`) you can avoid the script tag and add the following to your directives:

```
var Msal = require("exports-loader?Msal!../../../node_modules/msal/out/msal.js");
```

Comment: I am getting exception:
Unexpected '!' in 'exports-loader?Msal!./node_modules/msal/out/msal.js'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders import/no-webpack-loader-syntax

Comment: I was able to import using this but I am getting the following error: `Msal.UserAgentApplication is not a constructor`