# How to properly import and use the MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library for js) into a javascript (non typescript) react single page application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-ad-msal

i tried to import Msal into a reactjs app. As the app is create by create-react-app we have no webpack loader in the project itself. I can not get a reference to Msal. tried:

```
var Msal = require('msal/out/msal.js');
var Msal = require('msal');
import Msal from 'msal';
import {Msal} from 'msal';
```

There is always an empty Msal without the constructor for creating the connector.

```
var userAgentApplication = new **Msal**.UserAgentApplication("your_client_id", null, function (errorDes, token, error, tokenType) {
              // this callback is called after loginRedirect OR acquireTokenRedirect (not used for loginPopup/aquireTokenPopup)
        })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, msal is not a module, so it can't be imported [as noted in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44235823/2120317).  Hopefully it gets updated with module support in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msal 0.1.3` can be imported - see https://github.com/sunilbandla/vue-msal-sample