# Msal undefined in Angular 4.5 Service for Azure B2C authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, angular-services, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I am working on Angular 4.5 application and Azure B2C authentication work. I have separate app with my azure B2C configuration and is working so I know problem is in my code. I am getting error for Msal undefined.

I have install Msal library by

```
 npm install msal
```

but I am not sure if I need to add reference to package.json file before or after installation??

The Visual Studio Code doesn't give me any error but at browser it does.

### error

```
 ReferenceError: 'Msal' is not defined
 at MsalService (http://localhost:4000/0.chunk.js:15545:9)
 at createClass (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:11407:13)
 at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:11380:13)
 at createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:11214:5)
 at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:12679:17)
 at callViewAction (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:13138:13)
 at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:13047:13)
 at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:12716:5)
 at callViewAction (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:13138:13)
 at execComponentViewsAction (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:13047:13)
 at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:12716:5)
 at createRootView (http://localhost:4000/main.bundle.js:12584:5)
 at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:4000/main.bund
```

### Msal Service where error generating;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

   declare var bootbox: any;
   declare var Msal: any;

 @Injectable()
 export class MsalService{

 access_token: string;

 tenantConfig = {       
    tenant: 'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com',
    clientID: 'my client id xxx',
    signUpSignInPolicy: 'B2C_1_SiUpIn',
    b2cScopes: ["http://myb2cscope/App/Read"]
 };

 authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/" + this.tenantConfig.tenant + "/" + this.tenantConfig.signUpSignInPolicy;   

 /* B2C SignIn SignUp Policy Configuration*/
   clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
    this.tenantConfig.clientID, this.authority, 
    function (errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
        // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
    }
 );

  public login(): void {
    var _this = this;
     this.clientApplication.loginPopup(this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (idToken: any) {
         _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
             function (accessToken: any) {
                 _this.access_token = accessToken;
             }, function (error: any) {
                 _this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(_this.tenantConfig.b2cScopes).then(
                     function (accessToken: any) {
                         _this.access_token = accessToken;
                     }, function (error: any) {
                         bootbox.alert("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                     });
             })
     }, function (error: any) {
         bootbox.alert("Error during login:\n" + error);
     });
 }

 logout(): void {
     this.clientApplication.logout();
 };

 isOnline(): boolean {
     return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null; 
 };

 getProduct(): string
      {
          return "12 Apples";
      }
   }
```

I am not sure if I am missing very obvious or if there is way to confirm my install Msal library is working????

Answer (score 2):

msal.d.ts file in MSAL version 0.1.0 doesn't have export hence it cannot be refered as import in service class and browser will through this error 'module'

Later versions 0.1.3 of MSAL seem to work well now, I'm using version 0.1.3, and it a simple:

```
 import * as Msal from 'msal';
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using pure msal.js library, you can try using msal@angular:

npm install msal-angular --save

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_msal_package/msal.js"></script>` in your app.html or try this angular-msal package https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal-angular

Edit: The error you get `ReferenceError: 'Msal' is not defined` means that even if you installed 'Msal' lib, is not injected in the project.

Here is an example https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample

Comment: I am working on .. but no luck...  even I refer to right path .. angular is complaining that it is not module

Comment: [at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
[at-loader] ./src/app/security/Services/msal.service.ts:2:20
    TS2306: File 'C:/Developments/AntDev/Presentation/node_modules/msal/out/msal.d.ts' is not a module.

Comment: that is how I am trying to add reference==>                                           import {Msal} from 'node_modules/msal/out/msal';

Comment: i couldn't find something very specific with angular, so for now i would recommend adding the script like this https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample/blob/master/src/index.html

Comment: https://github.com/sunilbandla/msal-angular-sample/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.service.ts

Comment: apparently file doesn't have export and hence is not module so it won't work by importing...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44228493/how-to-properly-import-and-use-the-msal-microsoft-authentication-library-for-js

Comment: i have found solution, listed in my answer below